# "No such file or directory" when trying to include a file

Tags: php

Today I have a little issue where im trying to call a function inside a php class (Auth.php->GetNumOnline())

Im trying to call this from a class that handles all my "stats".

Here is my code:
Stats class

```
class statReciever
{

public function GetNumOnline()
{
    set_include_path("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}");
    include("../Authentication/Auth.php");
    $auth = new Auth();
    return $auth->NumOnline();
}
}
```

And here is a stripped down version of the Auth Class

```
class Auth
{
 public function NumOnline()
 {
    return 0;
 }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my directory:
[image: screenie]

Here is the error I receive:
    [Sun Mar 10 14:35:25 2013] [error] [client *MASKED*] PHP Warning:  include(./../Authentication/Auth.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/example.com/public_html/includes/statReciever.php on line 16, referer: http://example.com/

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: yes, by using `spl_autoload_register` in your bootstrap instead of littering your codebase with `include` calls

Comment: the Auth.php file is not included.. the warning is telling you that the file is not at that position...

Comment: @Alex, The screenshot proves the file does exist!

Comment: if you are including the "`statReciever`" in your main which is in your root.. then, when you include `Auth.php` as you wrote.. it won't be found

Comment: please go through these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+include+works+php

Comment: When you set the include path to the document root, you are _overwriting_ the existing include path, which includes `.`, so the new include path is looking for `..` as the directory _above the document root_, not above the current directory.

Comment: I include the statReciever like this include("./includes/statReciever.php"); from my index.php

Comment: Just don't call `set_include_path()` in that function, and it should work otherwise exactly as you have it.  Your old include path probably contains the correct `.` already.

Comment: answered below.. check that... I also provided an alternative for your path

Answer (score 1):

include_path is always calculated from the working dir of the first script.

Use `__DIR__` for always use the directory of the class as base path.

```
include(__DIR__ . "/../Authentication/Auth.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/projectFolder/Authentication/Auth.php');
```

to include your files.

When your project starts in `index.php` and you want to include a file which is including another file... then make sure that the another's file path is absolute! (based on `index.php` location)

For example, I had a constants file named `config.php` where I always defined variables like:

```
define('PROJECT_LOCATION', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/projectFolder');
```

And then I used this constant to include my files like:

```
include(PROJECT_LOCATION.'/Authentication/Auth.php');
```

or something like that...